# jQuery autocomplete return array

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Here's my code:

```
$("#input-search").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
            $.get('EmployeeSearchList.igx', { name: request.term }, 
            function(data) {
                response(data.split('\n'));
                }
            );
        }
    });
```

and EmployeeSearchList.igx returns this kind of format.

```
[{label:"JP Fortes", value:"199829"},{label:"Jeffrey Dante", value:"200507"}]
```

How can I view this in return?

```
<li value="199829">JP Fortes</li>
<li value="200507">Jeffrey Dante</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#input-search").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.get('EmployeeSearchList.igx', { name: request.term }, 
        function(data) {
            var html = "";
            for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
               html += '<li value="'+data[i].value+'">'+data[i].label+'</li>';
            }
            $("ul").append(html);
        });
    }
});
```

Something like this should do the trick. You may have to drill further into the `data` object, so just check what's returned to make sure you're looping through the right array.

Comment: You're right dude, but still no data only the loading gif views.How can I populate this in autocomplete? Is the $.get code affected the script? how about using ajax instead of get? wahhh! Im to crazy for this! @_@

Comment: sorry, misread the question! Have you checked out this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/